# not getting updated state value in react using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am using `functional components` .I have `2` radio buttons and a`submit` button.On submit button I am not able to get `updated value`.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-microservice-ywdoe?file=/src/App.js

step to reproduce

1. run the application.BY default radio button value is `no`
2. Change any of radio button to `yes`.then click submit button .it should show updated value of state.**but it is showing initial state why** ??

**button submit handler**

```
 const buttonHandler = useCallback(async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
  }, []);
```

if change `blank array to one item in array state like this`.it works correctly , but it re-render button component when I change the `state`. **any better solution**  ??? to prevent re-rendering and get updated state ?

```
 const buttonHandler = useCallback(async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);
```

Comment: `useChangeHandler` undefined in App.js. `userchangehandler.js` is empty in the sandbox. From the looks of your snippet here though I can see you've enclosed the initial state in the `useCallback` hook by using an empty dependency array. I think if you add `state` to the dependency it *should* work. TBH there probably also isn't a reason to memoize this callback anyway as `Submit` doesn't do anything other than render a button.

Comment: why do you want the button _not_ to re-render?

Comment: check updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-darwin-pi09b?file=/src/usechangehandler.js

Comment: @DrewReese updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-darwin-pi09b?file=/src/usechangehandler.js

Comment: Just tested it with `state` added to the `buttonHandler` useCallback dependency array, it works.

Comment: @Anthony see when I change `radio button values` it is not re-rendering for performance  .it is good . but in case of `button` it is re rendering whenever state change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `state` to the `buttonHandler` useCallback dependency array.

```
const buttonHandler = useCallback(async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(state);
}, [state]);
```

[image: Edit nifty-tree-5yrxq]

Alternatively, don't memoize the `buttonHandler` callback.

```
const buttonHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(state);
};
```

Comment: I got your point but I will optimise this ?? for performance wise `button` component is re-render again when state change. is it a best practice ?

Comment: why i am asking this because if i have multiple element in my form . when i change any component state it re-render `button` component

Comment: @user944513 This looks like it fully falls into the category of premature optimization. With the `useCallback` it is *necessary* for it to rerender since you need to update the callback to enclose the updated state. Since this occurs each state update, and ipso facto, each render cycle, the submit button gets rerendered anyway. Is there currently a performance issue by *not* using the memoized callback?